# How to draw a graph based on a known function?

Tags: image

Knowing the following code, how to draw a result similar to the following picture?

```
l = 0.2;
L = 0.1;
inc=Pi/2;
M=1;
a=0.999;
\[CapitalDelta][r_] := 
 r^2 + l^2 + a^2 - (2 M Sqrt[r^2 + l^2] + L (r^2 + l^2));
Derivative[1][\[CapitalDelta]][r] := 
 D[r^2 + l^2 + a^2 - (2 M Sqrt[r^2 + l^2] + L (r^2 + l^2)), r];
xi[r_] := (
 a^2 + l^2 + r^2 - (4 r \[CapitalDelta][r])/
  Derivative[1][\[CapitalDelta]][r])/a;
eta[r_] := (
 16 r^2 (a^2 - \[CapitalDelta][r]) \[CapitalDelta][r] + 
  8 r (l^2 + r^2) \[CapitalDelta][r] Derivative[1][\[CapitalDelta]][
    r] - (l^2 + r^2)^2 Derivative[1][\[CapitalDelta]][r]^2)/(
 a^2 Derivative[1][\[CapitalDelta]][r]^2);
arg[r_] := eta[r] + a^2*Cos[inc]^2 - (xi[r])^2*(Cos[inc]/Sin[inc])^2;
alpha = -xi[r]/Sin[inc];
beta = Sqrt[arg[r]];
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Remove `Derivative[1][Δ][r] := 
 D[r^2 + l^2 + a^2 - (2 M Sqrt[r^2 + l^2] + L (r^2 + l^2)), r]`